# Evaluate Concatenated Variable Names in Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm building a template to deploy a linked template *n* number of times using the `copy` function while incrementing the object variable (e.g. from `vmRole1` to `vmRole2`) that's being used but it seems that while I'm able to concatenate together a proper variable string (e.g. `variables('vmRole1').roleInstanceCount`) it never actually gets evaluated before being passed on to the linked template.

Is there any way that I can force the ARM template to actually evaluate the concatenated string inside the loop before sending it to the linked template?

**Variable Sample:**

```
"vmRole1": {
  ...
  "roleInstanceCount": 2,
  ...
}
```

**Resource Sample:**

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "name": "[concat('DeployRole',copyIndex(1) ,variables('vmRole1Name'))]",
  "copy": {
    "name": "rolecopy",
    "count": 2
  },
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "<proper URL here>",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      ...
      "roleInstanceCount": { "value": "[concat('variables(', variables('singleQuote'), 'vmRole', copyIndex(1), variables('singlequote'), ').roleInstanceCount')]" },
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple answer** - no.
**Weird answer** - maybe, if you use another set of nested templates to verify these values.
**Long answer** - you are doing this completely wrong. I have no idea why are you doing such a weird thing with trying to pretend you are building something dynamically...

Try doing it like this (using your route):

```
"value": "[variables(concat('vmRole', copyIndex())).roleInstanceCount]
```

But honestly, I'd convert that vmRole1\vmRole2...\vmRole100 nonsense into an array and reference objects like so:

```
"value": "[variables('vmReferenceArray')[copyIndex()].propertyX]"
```

and your variable would look like this:

```
"vmReferenceArray": [
    {
        propertyX: ...
        propertyY: ...
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: I spent way too many hours staring at this. Your first suggestion ( `"value": "[variables(concat('vmRole', copyIndex())).roleInstanceCount]` ) did the trick perfectly. I'd thought about the array, maybe I'll go back and change it.